# How to get the value from the localStorage object key? Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, local

I need your help. In `localStorage` I have the object in the example. I am using Angular. I need to extract the value of the first `linkedinMail` key. I tried to do it in several ways, but as a result in the console, I get the first curly brace `{`

Object fron localStorage

`{"linkedinMail": "mail.com", "password": "123"}`

The first option:

```
public linkedinEmailBody: any

const emailLoginLinkedin = localStorage.getItem('credsForJetLeadBE')
let [key, value] = Object.entries(emailLoginLinkedin)[0];
this.linkedinEmailBody = value;
console.log(this.linkedinEmailBody) // result: `{`
```

The second option:

```
public linkedinEmailBody: any

const emailLoginLinkedin = localStorage.getItem('credsForJetLeadBE')
const valueEmailLinkedin = Object.values(emailLoginLinkedin)[0];
this.linkedinEmailBody = valueEmailLinkedin
console.log(this.linkedinEmailBody) // result: `{`
```

The third option

```
public linkedinEmailBody: any

const emailLoginLinkedin = localStorage.getItem('credsForJetLeadBE')
const valueEmailLinkedin = emailLoginLinkedin[Object.keys(emailLoginLinkedin)[0]];
this.linkedinEmailBody = valueEmailLinkedin
console.log(this.linkedinEmailBody) // result: `{`
```

When I use standard JS, the value of the `linkedinMail` field comes to me fine, instead of `{`. What am I doing wrong? Thank you very much

Comment: Local storage stores strings

Comment: @DanielA.White Okay, and how to get the value of first string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LocalStorage, sessionStorage stores strings. To change it to it original type, you have to parse it like this:

const emailLoginLinkedin = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('credsForJetLeadBE'));

After that you can use any way you want to retrieve the first key,value pair.

Comment: Thank you a lot)))) I forgot about JSON object))

Answer (score 1):

Local storage stores the value as a string, so you need to use

```js
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('credsForJetLeadBE'))
```

to get the actual object.

This should work.

```js
const emailLoginLinkedin = JSON.parse( // (1)
    localStorage.getItem("credsForJetLeadBE")
);

let [key, value] = Object.entries(emailLoginLinkedin)[0];
let linkedinEmailBody = value;
console.log(linkedinEmailBody);
```

1. In local storage, you have a JSON string containing the object you're storing.

   In order for JavaScript to be able to work with it as an object, you need to call [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) on it.

Answer (score 1):

I'll provide you a whole example, because you **not only could have a problem in the GET, but in the SET**.

I'm not going to use the *"easy way"*, in order you to understand better, and then (when it works fine), you can go wherever complicated you want (**destructuring**, ...).

```
// Initial Declaration
interface IEmailLoginLinkedin = {
   linkedinMail: string; 
   password: string;
}

emailLoginLinkedin: IEmailLoginLinkedin;

// Initialize 
 this.emailLoginLinkedin =  { linkedinMail: 'mail.com',password: '123' };


// Set value
this.setEmailLoginLinkedin(this.emailLoginLinkedin);

// Get values
const emailLoginLinkedinObject: IEmailLoginLinkedin|null  = this.getEmailLoginLinkedin();

let linkedinMail: string;
let password: string;

if (emailLoginLinkedinObject) {

   linkedinMail= emailLoginLinkedinObject.linkedinMail;
   password = emailLoginLinkedinObject.password;

   // Or the same but with 'destructuring':({linkedinMail, password}) = emailLoginLinkedinObject;

} else {
console.log('emailLoginLinkedin not set in the localStorage');
}
```

And the methods for the access to the localStorage:

```
 
// Serialize and STORE the emailLoginLinkedin in localstore:
setEmailLoginLinkedin(emailLoginLinkedin: IEmailLoginLinkedin){
   const emailLoginLinkedinString:string = JSON.stringify( emailLoginLinkedin );
   localStorage.setItem('emailLoginLinkedin', emailLoginLinkedinString);
}

----
 
// READ the emailLoginLinkedin from localstorage and Deserialize
getEmailLoginLinkedin(): IEmailLoginLinkedin|null {
 
   const emailLoginLinkedinString:string|null =  localStorage.getItem('emailLoginLinkedin');
 
   if( emailLoginLinkedinString ){
       return JSON.parse(emailLoginLinkedinString);
   } else {
       return null;
   }
 
}
```